# Unable to set Pojo Object variable with an external value during JaxB MoXY Unmarshalling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, jaxb, eclipselink

I am trying the above approach that you have mentioned for NodeAdaptar, but I am getting null for my element.

**Scenario**:
I have to set the value of variable defined in my Java Model(POJO) Class with a value, coming externally(not part of the input XML). This value will be used in some calculation post unmarshal.

input XML: its a huge one. I am able to unmarshall it correctly.

POJO Class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MainModelClass {


    @XmlPath("abc/def/Result/text()")
    @XmlElement(name="Result")
    private String result;


    @XmlPath("/abc/def/Score/text()")
    @XmlElement(name="Score")
    private String score;

///This is where I want to populate the external value ///
    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PCNDateAdaptar.class)
    private PCNDate pcnDateObject;

    public PCNDate getPcnDateObject() {
        return pcnDateObject;
    }

    public void setPcnDateObject(PCNDate pcnDateObject) {
        this.pcnDateObject = pcnDateObject;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

// Block for overridden toString() //

}
```

Adaptar Class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class PCNDateAdaptar extends XmlAdapter<Integer, PCNDate> {

    private PCNDate pcnDateObject;

    public void setPcnDateObject(PCNDate pcnDateob) {
        this.pcnDateObject = pcnDateob;
    }

    @Override
    public PCNDate unmarshal(Integer v) throws Exception {

        if(v == null)
            return this.pcnDateObject;
        else
            return this.pcnDateObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer marshal(PCNDate v) throws Exception {
        if(v == null)
            return null;
        else
            return null;
    }

}
```

PCNDate.class:

```
public class PCNDate {

    private Integer processControlDate;

    public Integer getProcessControlDate() {
        return processControlDate;
    }
    public void setProcessControlDate(Integer pcn) {
        this.processControlDate = pcn;
    }
}
```

Unmarshaller Method:

```
    public static <T> T getXMLSnippetObject(String xmlString, Class<T> modelClass, XmlAdapter<?, ?> xmlAdapterObject) throws XMLStreamException, JAXBException {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(modelClass);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        unmarshaller.setAdapter(xmlAdapterObject);
        InputStream xmlInputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(xmlString);
        XMLInputFactory2 xmlInputFactory = (XMLInputFactory2)XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true);
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isNamespaceAware", true);
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isReplacingEntityReferences", true);
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.P_AUTO_CLOSE_INPUT, true);
        //xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.P_DTD_OVERRIDE, false);
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.P_REPORT_PROLOG_WHITESPACE, false);
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.P_PRESERVE_LOCATION,false);
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.P_INTERN_NS_URIS, true);
        XMLStreamReader2 xmlStreamReader = (XMLStreamReader2) xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(xmlInputStream);

T objectInstance = (T) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, modelClass));

        return objectInstance;

    }
```

Main Calling Class:

```
public class XMLparsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, JAXBException, IOException {

String xmlString = // Xml String //
MainModelClass modelObj = null;
        Integer pcnDate = 20171010;

   // PCNDate & PCNDateAdapter are both no-arg-constructor classes for JAXB purpose 
        PCNDate pcnObj = new PCNDate();
        pcnDateObj.setProcessControlDate(pcnDate);

        PCNDateAdaptar pcndateAdaptar = new PCNDateAdaptar();
        pcndateAdaptar.setPcnDateObject(pcnObj);

modelObj = XmlUtilsStAX.getXMLSnippetObject(xmlString, MainModelClass.class, pcndateAdaptar);

}
```

Result:
The whole Xml String is getting correctly parsed. Only MainModelClass's pcnDateObject is null, result & score have values. I want pcnDateObject to have 20171010.

I don't know, what I am missing, please help.

Comment: Is your pcndateAdaptar instance being called? The mappings seems like they would use an empty PCNDateAdaptar to handle the conversation and might explain why you get nulls. If you are relying on the unmarshaller.setAdapter method to pass in an instance, I believe the javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#setAdapter(javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter) )implies you might be using it wrong, and would need to specify the class you want it used for.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I tried passing the Adapter class in unmarshaller.setAdapte, but not able to pass it in a generic way in the getXMLSnippetObject method. How can I pass that? Could you please help me with that.